# How to place cdk-overlay-container inside cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport instead of document body

Tags: angular, viewport, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll, angular-cdk-overlay

I have a table component with cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport being used in it. Each row inside the viewport has an icon when clicked opens up a menu overlay component. I noticed that when I open the menu it creates the cdk-overlay-container and covers the page's entire body. This is causing issues because when I scroll up or down the menu goes beyond the viewport's bounds. I want the menu to be within the viewport. Is there a way to have the overlay be placed within the viewport instead of it being automatically created after my table ontop of everything else?